# Concatenate static value while exporting CSV file using fputcsv in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, excel, csv, fputcsv

I am using below code to export CSV file using fputcsv in PHP. Code works proper and CSV file generates. All the values/records are coming from database. But I want to add dollar ($) symbol with some of column values.

Code for exporting CSV file.

```
        $filename1 = "All Months.csv";
        ob_end_clean();
        $fp1 = fopen('php://output', 'w');

        ob_start();
        header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename1);

        fputcsv($fp1, array('Month', 'Year', 'Total Production', 'Credit Adjustments', 'Net Production', 'Hygiene Production', 'Collections', 'Account Receivable Total', 'New Patients', 'Break Even Points', 'Net Income', 'Hygiene %'));

        $query = $db->query("SELECT Month, Year, Total_Production, Credit_Adjustments, Net_Production, Hygiene_Production, Collections, AC_Receivable_Total, New_Patients, Break_Even_Points, Net_Income, Hygiene FROM clientsdata WHERE Client_Id = '".$userID."'");
        while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            fputcsv($fp1, $row);
        } 

        exit();
```

Snapshot of exporting file -

[image]

Comment: `$row['field']  = '$' . $row['field'];`

Comment: @splash58 - Thanks it works. Actually I was using like this $row->field = '$'.$row->field and it doesn't work. Thanks again.

Comment: `FETCH_ASSOC)` returns array but not object. that's why it did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want just to add $ sign you can do it this way:

```
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $row['the_field_you_want'] = '$'.$row['the_field_you_want']
    fputcsv($fp1, $row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While using select query itself you can concat $ symbol. Like below

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT concat('$',Net_Income) as Net_Income FROM clientsdata WHERE Client_Id = '".$userID."'");
        while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            fputcsv($fp1, $row);
        }
```